# How to add space between histograms (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, histogram

[image]

How can I add space between these histograms. Pretty new in python

Comment: I'm thinking either `plt.subplots_adjust` or `plt.tight_layout` however it's hard for us to really recommend any changes to your code, because you've provided nothing for us to work with. Please update the question to include actual code (not a screenshot) that we can work with to help you out.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Hi, thanks for your reply. I found a way plt.tight_layout()

Comment: If you've solved the problem yourself, please consider answering your own question with the code you used to resolve the issue, so that if others have the same problem in the future, they can use your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way plt.tight_layout()